# Segmentation Fault in C. Trying to concatenate the command line arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcat

I'm trying to concatenate the command line arguments into a string. I used the pointer of character type to declare the string initially.

```
char *str;
    strcpy(str, argv[1]);
    int i = 2;
    while(i < argc) {
        realloc(str, sizeof(str) + sizeof(argv[i]) + 1);
        str = strcat(str,argv[i]);
        i+=1;
    }
printf("%s", str);
free(str);
```

As you can see I am reallocating the block of memory in order to concatenate the new String. But I get Segmentation Fault: 11

Comment: `sizeof(str)` does not do what you think it does.  It will usually be 8 or 4, depending on your platform.  `sizeof(argv[i])` is the same thing.

Comment: besides that, your very first `strcpy()` (before the loop) already tries to copy data using an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str;
```

This just creates a pointer. You can generally point a memory location with a pointer but you can't copy data to a pointer as it doesn't itself have storage memory.

You will first have to allocate a memory:

```
str = (char *)malloc (sizeof(argv[1]) * sizeof(char));
```

Or you can allocate a char buffer instead and then strcpy:

```
char str[MAX_STR_LENGTH] = {0};
strcpy (str, argv[1]);
```

In the second case, str is also a pointer to str[0] and hence the first element of str char buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *str;
```

Memory not allocated for above char pointer before `strcpy`.Use `malloc/calloc` to allocate memory.

Also you can not use `sizeof` because `sizeof` any pointer is `8` or `4` bytes according platform.

Also for `sizeof(argv[i]) + 1`.I think it should be `strlen(argv[i]) + 1`